# Scala self type with dependent typing

Tags: scala, dependent-type, self-type

This does not compile:

```
trait FileSystem {
    type P <: Path[this.type]
}

trait Path[S <: FileSystem] { self: fileSystem.P =>
    val fileSystem: S
}
```

How can a self-type constraint be dependent on a value member in that trait?

Answer (score 4):

It cannot (and not sure what it would mean).

```
trait FileSystem {
    type P <: Path[this.type]
}

trait Path[S <: FileSystem] { self: S#P =>
    val fileSystem: S
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm doing right now. However this is not as strict as I want: I'd like that `self` must be an instance of the dependent type in `fileSystem.P`. So self type constraints can only refer to types in the generic type parameters list, not type members or dependent types in value members?

Comment: @TongfeiChen yes. You can't refer anything that goes after this self-constraint. Imagine you could refer. How are you going to instantiate such type? It has to be a subtype of something that it yet to be defined inside of it. This doesn't make sense.

Comment: However in dotty, generic type constraints are actually encoded by type members. The dependent type depends on a `val`, which is fixed at initialization time, instead of a `var`.

Answer (score 1):

Well I wouldn't do it, but you can; just put `Path` *inside* `FileSystem`:

```
trait AnyPath[S <: FileSystem] { self: S#P =>
  val fileSystem: S
}

trait FileSystem { thisFileSystem =>
  type P <: Path
  trait Path extends AnyPath[thisFileSystem.type]{ self: thisFileSystem.P =>
    lazy val fileSystem = thisFileSystem
  }
}

case object SomeFileSystem extends FileSystem {
  type P = ReallyConcretePath
  case class ReallyConcretePath() extends Path
}
```